# Trigger Alexa Remotely

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

Is it possible to trigger Alexa remotely i.e I have a scenario where based on some action on Mobile App Alexa should be triggered and the response provided will be read out by echo dot.

Varun

Comment: My question is related how does Alexa trigger the alarm once it is set by the user

Comment: alarms are built into the hardware of the device, totally different than the cloud-based alexa services. Writing built-in features is a perk of being an amazon develop

Comment: If you're using this for a home project you can use the  Amazon Alexa Skills Kit on a device like a Raspberry Pi.  Then you can still have access to Alexa but you have more control and could make it receive notifications since you control the hardware.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to trigger a response without the user interacting with the Alexa-enabled device. But it looks like this may be changing soon: https://www.theverge.com/2017/5/16/15647074/alexa-notifications-being-added-amazon-echo

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers - Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for how to answer questions.

Comment: Hey Toby. I am a little curious about this. I did answer the question, then gave a link with some new information that provided new context that's coming soon. Is that not ok? Just wanting to understand. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Currently there isn't a way to trigger a response from the device without interacting with the device it's self. Even skills created for the device by third parties currently only have access to get a response immediately (approximately with-in 10 seconds) after an interaction.

Comment: I think the period to respond is even shorter. From my experience it's only 5 seconds or less.

Comment: Totally possible @unnu I'm not sure of the exact time right off.

Comment: It's supposed to be 8 seconds from end of speech detection to response started. Developers should set their Lambdas to time out after 7 seconds because of this.

Comment: Actually I was looking the other day and notice it is configurable up to either 30 or 45 seconds but the default is set to 8